# Select nested fields in filtered aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I aggregate, filter nested array and project selected nested fields?

I have the following data:

```js
{
  "teacher": "Ben",
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "Liz",
      "age": 8,
      "pets": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Jon",
      "age": 9,
      "pets": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Eva",
      "age": 9,
      "pets": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

..and want to query to get this result:

```js
{
  "teacher": "Ben",
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "Jon",
      "pets": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Eva",
      "pets": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I can filter by some age but how can I return only the `name` and `pets` fields in the nested student data? Have tried to project those fields in all ways I could think of without luck so I'm likely looking in the wrong place I guess.

```js
db.classes.aggregate([
  { "$match": {} },
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "teacher": 1,
    "students": {
      "$filter": {
        input: "$students",
        cond: {
          "$eq": [ "$$this.age", 9 ],
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a `$project` stage

```js
 //previous stages 
 {
    $project: {
      "students.age": 0
    }
  }
```

or you could use the [`$unset`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) stage to remove fields you dont want

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      teacher: 1,
      students: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$students",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.age", 9 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "students.age" }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qD7uCYyGuhj)

i think it would be even cleaner with an `$addFields` followed by an `$unset`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  {
    $addFields: {
      students: {  //fields you just want to add, here overwrites students
        $filter: {
          input: "$students",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.age", 9 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: [ "students.age", "_id" ] } //remove just the ones not needed
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ztn4blBcuVo)

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm. Thanks for all variations, @cmgchess!